# I meant to upvote but system claims I downvoted - what can I do?

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes

I thought I upvoted the top answer on [backbone.js / access view from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631911/backbone-js-access-view-from-model/5648650#5648650) but today Stack Overflow claims I downvoted. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I see you managed to reverse this now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the system says you downvoted, you downvoted. Your vote is now locked and you can't change it, except when the post is edited (I see that you suggested an edit already, but I'm not sure it will be approved as it doesn't really make the post any clearer).

Otherwise, you shouldn't worry about a single downvote. We are humans, we make mistakes all the time.

Comment: Yeah, what doesn't make sense is I definitely upvoted because I saw the vote total go up. Only this morning I noticed the change.

Comment: @ykay might be that other people voting at the same time hid the truth from you

Comment: I don't mind if I made a mistake but I hate for it to hurt someone else

Comment: @gimby that answer is 5 years old and has a score of 8 it isn't a voting hotspot.

Comment: @MartinSmith Okay (shame on me for not looking), then I agree it is strange. Just note that you're not hurting anyone. You downvoted content, not a person. The fact that someone loses a couple of internet points is something the site does, not you.

Comment: @Gimby if you don't think unexplained drive by down votes irritate people you can't have spent much time on meta. And the site does it as a direct result of the OP's actions it is not an act of God.

Answer (score 1):

You can just leave a comment on the answer explaining to the answerer that you must have misclicked and your vote is locked in unless edited.

They may well find something that they can polish and can respond to let you know when done.

This is not a prescribed use of comments but IMO people should be pragmatic about this.